# Is it possible to use a UIPickerView with an if function depending (for example) on an UISegmentedControll?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to create a Picker View in a TextField depending on a SegmentedControll.

Just started to code with some if functions...but its not working because the func does not return a Int.

```
func functionOne() {
        createJobToolBar()
        aufgabenPicker = UIPickerView()
        aufgabenPicker?.delegate = self
        aufgabenPicker?.dataSource = self

        jobTF.inputView = aufgabenPicker
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if categorySC.isEnabledForSegment(at: 1) {
            return jobsHaus.count
        }else if categorySC.isEnabledForSegment(at: 2) {
            return jobsGarten.count
        }else if categorySC.isEnabledForSegment(at: 3) {
            return jobsBetreuung.count
        }else if categorySC.isEnabledForSegment(at: 4) {
            return jobsSonstiges.count
        }
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if categorySC.isEnabledForSegment(at: 1) {
            return jobsHaus[row]
        }else if categorySC.isEnabledForSegment(at: 2) {
            return jobsGarten[row]
        }else if categorySC.isEnabledForSegment(at: 3) {
            return jobsBetreuung[row]
        }else if categorySC.isEnabledForSegment(at: 4) {
            return jobsSonstiges[row]
        }
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if categorySC.isEnabledForSegment(at: 1) {
            jobTF.text = jobsHaus[row]
        }else if categorySC.isEnabledForSegment(at: 2) {
            jobTF.text = jobsGarten[row]
        }else if categorySC.isEnabledForSegment(at: 3) {
            jobTF.text = jobsBetreuung[row]
        }else if categorySC.isEnabledForSegment(at: 4) {
            jobTF.text = jobsSonstiges[row]
        }
    }
```

Current error message because of the missing return: "Missing return in a function expected to return 'Int'"

Comment: Why are you checking if each segment is enabled? Shouldn't you be looking at the value of `selectedSegmentIndex` ?

Comment: Of course...i don't know why i miss that one ... But my problem with the function is the same if i think correct, right?

Comment: You should review [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Missing+return+in+a+function+expected+to+return+). Many of them will help you solve this.

Answer (score 0):

In your `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int)` method you return a value based on the basis of a number of `if ... else` statements.  These may cover all your possible scenarios but the compiler can't infer that, and can see a possibility where all four checks fail and therefore no value is returned.

There are a few approaches to fixing this:

1. after the last `if` put in a fatalError to crash out

```
//cut earlier code for brevity
  else if categorySC.isEnabledForSegment(at: 4) {
            return jobsSonstiges.count
  }
  fatalerror("Invalid segment logic")
}
```

2. Return a random number, on the basis that if your logic is correct it the code flow should never get that far:

```
//cut earlier code for brevity

  else if categorySC.isEnabledForSegment(at: 4) {
            return jobsSonstiges.count
  }
  return 999
}
```

3. Omit the last `if` check on the basis that it is the only possible value left, and just return the value:

```
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if categorySC.isEnabledForSegment(at: 1) {
            return jobsHaus[row]
        }else if categorySC.isEnabledForSegment(at: 2) {
            return jobsGarten[row]
        }else if categorySC.isEnabledForSegment(at: 3) {
            return jobsBetreuung[row]
        }else {
            return jobsSonstiges[row]
        }
    }
```

My preference, at least during development, would be for option 1 so that I find out if I've made a logic error.